# How to hide actions in faceted search results in alfresco 5.2+aikau-1.0.101

Tags: alfresco-share, aikau

How to hide actions in faceted search results?.we are using alfresco 5.2+aikau-1.10.101

[image]

Comment: You need to override this `createActionsRenderer()` in https://github.com/Alfresco/Aikau/blob/develop/aikau/src/main/resources/alfresco/search/AlfSearchResult.js. Let me see, is there any other ways of doing it.

Comment: what to do in that createActionsRenderer() and how to override createActionsRenderer??